# Updating label in time shows up all at once

Tags: ios, swift, label, updating

I have a label that I would like to populate with a number of dots, each dot appearing in sequence, separated by 0.1 second

```
func setUpDots(numberOfDots: Int) {
    for dots in 1...numberOfDots {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.setLabelToDots(numberOfDots: dots)
            }
            usleep(100000)      // wait 0.1 sec between showing each dot
        }
    }
}

func setLabelToDots(numberOfDots: Int) {
    let dots = Array( repeating: ".", count: numberOfDots).joined()
    myLabel.text = dots
    myLabel.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

But all the dots appear on the label at once

What should I do to get the right effect of the dots showing up with the specified delay between them?

Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: You can't use a `for-loop` this way, as the your executing `numberOfDots` tasks, which are all running (almost) at the same time and then waiting ... for nothing. An immediate solution might be to use a `Timer` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, your `for-loop` is doing something similar to...

```
for dots in 1...numberOfDots {
    self.setLabelToDots(numberOfDots: dots)
}
```

This is because each task is been allowed to execute at the same and the delay is having no effect on when the next one will run.

You "could" use a serial queue or you could use dependent operation queue, but a simpler solution might be to just use a `Timer`

This will allow you to setup a "delay" between ticks and treat the timer as a kind of pseudo loop, for example

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

    let numberOfDots = 10
    var dots = 0

    var timer: Timer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myLabel.text = ""
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        guard timer == nil else {
            return
        }
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(tick), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func tick() {
        dots += 1
        guard dots <= numberOfDots else {
            timer?.invalidate()
            timer = nil
            dots = 0
            return
        }
        numberOfDots(dots)
    }

    func numberOfDots(_ numberOfDots: Int) {
        // You could just use string consternation instead,
        // which would probably be quicker
        let dots = Array( repeating: ".", count: numberOfDots).joined()
        myLabel.text = dots
        myLabel.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

There are plenty of other examples about, but you should also have a look at the [documentation for `Timer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer)